# Python - alternative for multiple os.system command

Tags: python, python-3.x

Below are the shell commands, that does few variable and file manipulation and uploads the final file to a repository.

Using repetitive os.system() is one option. Is there a simpler and elegant way to address this ?

Even with the `os.system()`, I'm facing issues with quotes and the variable replacement is throwing error.

I don't want to club these commands as a script and execute it :) Any input would be really helpful, thanks.

```
target_folder = tmp_folder+'/tmp'+str(count)
FILE_TYPE = "bundle"
FILE_NAME = "solution"

    os.system('''
    set +x
    file_name_wo_ext="$(cat 'target_folder'/*.yaml| grep -i name | awk '{print $2}' | awk '{print $1}')"
    output_folder="/home/'FILE_NAME'/'FILE_TYPE'/${file_name_wo_ext}/"
    tar_file_name=$(ls $output_folder | grep tar.gz)
    file_path="/home/"+FILE_NAME"/"+FILE_TYPE+"/${file_name_wo_ext}/${tar_file_name}"
    mv $file_path "`basename $file_path .tar.gz`.tgz"
    wget command to upload the file
    ''')
```

**Error:**

ls: cannot access '/home/+FILE_NAME/+FILE_TYPE+/cat': No such file or directory

ls: cannot access '+target_folder/*.yaml|': No such file or directory

OS: Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: Which OS/OSes are you going to target

Comment: There's no reason why Python _would_ interpolate your FILE_NAME/FILE_TYPE variables into the script like that.

Comment: Why not write pure python code for this? @Goku

Comment: Read about the string formatting [DOCS](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#formatted-string-literals)

Comment: My bad, I've added the OS details.

Comment: That's some horrible shell script. What's `awk '{print $2}' | awk '{print $1}'` supposed to accomplish?  More generally, can you explain what the code is supposed to do? Code which doesn't work is a terrible way to explain what you actually want.

Comment: Not really sure what your script does in terms of awk (i'm bad with awk :)), but considering filename search and moving I would also recommend to do it in pure python instead of the os calls. 
I did use fnmatch and shutil python packages in the past and it was a very powerful combination and also OS-independent(not sure if you need that).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An approximation of your shell script in Python might be something like this.

Do note that your original script will behave in undefined ways if there are e.g. multiple `name` lines in the YAML, or multiple `.tar.gz`es...

```
import glob
import os


def find_filename_wo_ext(target_folder):
    for yaml_filename in glob.glob(os.path.join(target_folder, "*.yaml")):
        with open(yaml_filename, "r") as yaml_file:
            for line in yaml_file:
                if "name" in line.lower():
                    return line.partition(" ")[-1]  # might be wrong :)


def main():
    tmp_folder = "/tmp"
    count = 1

    target_folder = os.path.join(tmp_folder, f"tmp{count}")
    FILE_TYPE = "bundle"
    FILE_NAME = "solution"

    file_name_wo_ext = find_filename_wo_ext(target_folder)
    output_folder = os.path.join("/home", FILE_TYPE, FILE_NAME, file_name_wo_ext)
    tar_file_name = list(
        glob.glob(os.path.join(output_folder, "*.tar.gz"))
    )[0]
    file_path = os.path.join(output_folder, tar_file_name)
    os.rename(file_path, os.path.splitext(file_path)[0] + ".tgz")
    os.system("wget...")
```

Comment: `return line.partition(" ")[-1]` should perhaps be `return line.partition(" ")[1]`

Comment: @tripleee `line.partition(" ")[1]` would return the space. ;-)

Comment: Oops, I guess `line.split()[1]` would be more like what I was looking for. Awk splits on any sequence of whitespace and `$2` fetches the second field out of that.

Comment: Yeah, I didn't feel like figuring out what the double awk does in OP's post, to be honest. Your interpretation could well be right.

Comment: @AKX : Thanks a lot !! I did overcomplicate it .. Appreciate your help again..

Answer (score 0):

Multiple `os.system` commands are generally a bad idea, because you start a brand new shell for each command, which prevents to use shell level variables, or change the environment in one command and use it in the next one.

I would use `subprocess` to start one single shell, and then send all the commands to its standard input:

- one single shell execution
- you can freely use `set` commands to change the behaviour of that shell or set variables
- you have full control(*) on what is written to the standard output and standard error streams

---

(*) but you cannot expect to read something from the output streams before the end of the shell...